# Is dibromine a Lewis acid or base?

Tags: acid-base

Is $\ce{Br2}$ a Lewis acid or base?
As it has both, empty orbitals and lone pairs, so if separately asked without any reaction what would we consider it?

Comment: Without any reaction, it is _nothing_. Within a reaction, it can be either. There is nothing unusual about that.

Answer (score -1):

Ralph Pearson classified all Lewis acids and bases as hard and soft acids and bases. Br2 and Br+ are soft Lewis acids and Br- has properties in between soft bases and hard bases. Hence Br2 is considered to be a soft Lewis acid.
Soft acids have large acceptor atoms of low positive charge, high polarisability and low electronegativity. Hard acids have small acceptor atoms of low polarisability and high electronegativity.

Comment: $\ce{Br2 + H2O <=> HBr + BrOH}$ is only one example to show that this general statement cannot be true. It is always dependent on the reaction conditions.

Comment: The reaction should be mentioned. But the question was what is Br2 in general considered to be. We say HNO3 is an acid inspite of the well known reactions in which it is a base. Similarly, Br2 in general, is considered to be a soft Lewis acid.

Comment: enlighten me in which reactions $\ce{HNO3}$ is a base, please.

Comment: In nitration mixture, H2SO4 being a stronger acid abstracts a proton from HNO3 and HNO3 is a base in that reaction. Thus, in the presence of a stronger acid, HNO3 acts as a base.

Comment: even though your wording does not make any sense, I get what you mean. In any case, considering dibromine as an acid is questionable at best. Generalisations of this kind just distort chemistry for the learning, and lead to wrong conclusions in the long term. It is clearly both, and neither. You are simply offering a deceivingly simple solution.

Comment: I agree and understand but since the question itself was about generalisation, I made use of HSAB theory to find out whether Br2 is an acid or a base from its chemical properties.